# WTSClientInfo returns NULL on Windows 10 OS Over RDP Connection

Tags: windows, winapi, remote-access, remote-desktop, terminal-services

I am remotely connecting to Windows 10 Client OS through RDP client. When I collected `WTSIsRemoteSession` and `WTSClientProtocolType` using `WTSQuerySessionInformationW`() I correctly received that it was a remote session and protocol was RDP. However, when I tried to collect Client info as follows, the condition for AF_INET fails and Client Device Id is also blank. Need to know what I may be missing here. 
I noticed that all of the `PWTSCLIENTA` data was null. Strange thing was that, the query function itself did not fail.Following is my code.

```
if (WTSQuerySessionInformationW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, WTSClientInfo, &pData, &bytesReturned)){
            PWTSCLIENTA address = (PWTSCLIENTA)pData;
            printf("\tWTSQuerySessionInformationW - session %d - %s returned \"%p\"\n", WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, "WTSClientInfo", pData);
            if (AF_INET == address->ClientAddressFamily)
            {
                printf("\n\tClient Address : %d.%d.%d.%d\n", address->ClientAddress[2], address->ClientAddress[3], address->ClientAddress[4], address->ClientAddress[5]);
            }
            printf("\tClient DeviceId : %s\n\n", address->DeviceId);
    }
```

Comment: you need use `ULONG cb;
  WINSTATIONREMOTEADDRESS ra;
  if (WinStationQueryInformationW(0, LOGONID_CURRENT, WinStationRemoteAddress, &ra, sizeof(ra), &cb))`

Comment: use [*winsta.h*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tsts/ce70794f-2138-43e8-bf6c-2c147887d6a2) and you need [`WINSTATIONREMOTEADDRESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tsts/5b5a44b3-155f-4159-aad9-794e97275a3f) - returned by `WinStationRemoteAddress`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `WTSQuerySessionInformationW()`, but you are casting `pData` to `PWTSCLIENTA` when you need to cast it to `PWTSCLIENTW` instead.  As such, you are accessing the `ClientAddressFamily`, `ClientAddress`, and `DeviceId` fields using the wrong byte offsets.

Also, make sure you handle the possibility of the `ClientAddressFamily` being `AF_INET6` instead of `AF_INET`.

Try something more like this:

```
PWTSCLIENTW pData;
if (WTSQuerySessionInformationW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, WTSClientInfo, (LPWSTR*)&pData, &bytesReturned)){
    printf("\tWTSQuerySessionInformationW - session %d - %s returned \"%p\"\n", WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, "WTSClientInfo", pData);
    char ipAddress[46];
    if (inet_ntop(pData->ClientAddressFamily,pData->ClientAddress), ipAddress, sizeof(ipAddress)))
    {
        printf("\n\tClient Address : %s\n", ipAddress);
    }
    printf("\tClient DeviceId : %ls\n\n", pData->DeviceId);
    WTSFreeMemory(pData);
}
```

Comment: yes, this correct. however i in self test some time view that `WTSQuerySessionInformationW` with this or with `WTSClientAddress` not return address. (say if client not on windows) [*The client network address is reported by the RDP client itself when it connects to the server*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/ns-wtsapi32-wts_client_address). but `WinStationQueryInformationW` always return actual client ip address, how it view host comp

Comment: @Remy thanks for this help, I am new to WinAPIs. What is the difference between these two APIs? In the docs as I see it seems to be exactly same.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Your solution was better than my code but gave me a wrong Client IP and Device Id was blank again.

Comment: printf("\n\t1-Client Address : %d.%d.%d.%d\n", address->ClientAddress[0], address->ClientAddress[1], address->ClientAddress[2], address->ClientAddress[3]);  This shows me correct IP Address. But Anyways you helped me by correcting my type -cast error. Thanks. Client DeviceId is still blank.

Comment: @ultimatecause you should still let the OS format the IP address string for you. I fixed my code to not offset the `ClientAddress` anymore. As for the `DeviceId`, I couldn't say why that is empty. Maybe the WTS API simply doesn't know the adapter used for the connection, who knows.